# How can I execute only one tab of content in Android studio?

Tags: java, android

When I press tab 3, it will toast the message of tab 0, tab1, tab2, tab3.
However, it displays the correct content of tab 3. 
How can I only execute the content of tab 3?  And why it will execute others pages?

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);            
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
}
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    } @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
        System.out.println("This is the currnet position : " + position);
        if (position == 0) {
            Tab0Index tab0 = new Tab0Index();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tab1 active " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return tab0;
        } else if (position == 1) {
            Tab2Top10 tab2 = new Tab2Top10();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tab2 active " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return tab2;
        } else if (position == 2) {
            Tab3UserRanking tab3 = new Tab3UserRanking();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tab3 active " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return tab3;
        } else if (position == 3) {
            Tab4Profile tab4 = new Tab4Profile();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tab4 active " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return tab4;
        } else if (position == 4) {
            Tab5Setting tab5 = new Tab5Setting();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tab5 active " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return tab5;
        }else{
           return null;
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return mNumOfTabs;
    } }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tab1 active " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in `SectionsPagerAdapter` . The view page already loads previous and next page when you select a page. So change toast to onResume of each fragment(Pages). for example. for Tab 1 fragment's onResume(), use below code

```
     @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tab1 active " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
           }
        }
```

Comment: However, I don't want the view page loads previous and next page when I select a page, is there any ways to do that?

Comment: For example, I just want to force one of the tab pages to start an intent(other activity), but not three of tabs are forced to do that.

Comment: Using ViewPager you can't do that. but you can check if your tab page is active or not by using getUserVisibleHint()